# Mostrar valor do input ao clicar no botao

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço pra mostrar valor que digitei no `input` após clicar no botão?
o meu sempre retorna vazio:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("usuario").value;

var usuario = $("#usuario").value; //document.getElementById("user").value;  //  $("#user").value;
var senha = $("#pwd").value;

function Enviar() {
  $("#enviar").on('click', function() {
    alert(usuario)
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="search">
  <input id="term" type="text" value="" />
  <button id="hit" type="button" name="">Search</button>
</div>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="controls">
      <label for="id">User ID:</label>
      <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" />
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
      <input type="submit" id="enviar" onclick="Enviar()" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Utilize `$("#usuario").val()` e remova o `type` do botão *Submit*.

Comment: não tem sentido tirar submit se nao vai perder propriedade do buttom

Comment: Existe um type="button" nesse caso não seria melhor?

Comment: Não prestei atenção e achei que era um `button`. De qualquer forma, utilize `preventDefault` ou utilize um `button` (semanticamente é melhor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Várias coisas que deverão ser corrigidas:

1. Você tratou evento `click` duas vezes, tanto no atributo `onclick` do elemento quanto em jQuery com a função `on`, basta apenas uma delas;
2. Você acessou o atributo `value` com jQuery, mas isso se faz no JS vanilla. Para buscar o valor do elemento no jQuery, use a função `val()`;
3. Você buscou os valores dos campos fora da função, o que fará com que eles serão executados quando a página for carregada - e quando é carregada os campos estão vazios. Você precisa obter os valores dentro da função;
4. Use a função `preventDefault` para evitar que o formulário seja submetido, já que está usando um botão `submit`;

Veja como ficaria:

```js
$("#enviar").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
  var senha = $("#pwd").val();
  alert(usuario)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="search">
  <input id="term" type="text" value="" />
  <button id="hit" type="button" name="">Search</button>
</div>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="controls">
      <label for="id">User ID:</label>
      <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" />
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
      <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está pegando o valor do campo fora da função, logo ele será vazio porque ao carregar a página o campo não tem nada, além de estar pegando o valor de forma incorreta. Em jQuery use-se `.val()` e não `value`:

```
$("#usuario").val();
```

E não precisa colocar o evento dentro de uma função e chamar a função através de um `onclick`. Basta criar um evento `submit` e pegar os valores dos campos dentro do evento:

```
$("form").on('submit', function() {
   var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
   var senha = $("#pwd").val();
   alert(usuario)
});
```

Ao submeter o formulário irá executar a função evento, pegando os valores atuais.

O HTML e script ficariam assim:

```js
var x = $("usuario").val(); // não entendi pra que esta linha serve(?)

$("form").on('submit', function() {
   var usuario = $("#usuario").val(); //document.getElementById("user").value;  //  $("#user").value;
   var senha = $("#pwd").val();
   alert(usuario)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <input id="term" type="text" value="" />
  <button id="hit" type="button" name="">Search</button>
</div>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="controls">
      <label for="id">User ID:</label>
      <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" />
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
      <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Fato *não tão curioso assim*: ao utilizar o evento `submit` no lugar do `click` o código ainda funcionará se o formulário for submetido através de outros meios que não sejam o clique. Como geralmente isso é desejado, costuma ser melhor usá-lo, de fato, no lugar do clique.

Answer (score 1):

Altera a sua função pra pegar o valor atualizado:

```
function Enviar() {
  $("#enviar").on('click', function() {
    alert($("#usuario").val())
  });
}
```

Se você quiser que ele ainda continue na página mude o type="submit" para type"button" no seu botão.
Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Se ele tirar o `type='submit'` o campo ficará sem o atributo, fazendo com que o navegador o trate como um campo de texto. Qual a razão de fazer isso?

Comment: o problema é que quero armazenar em 2 varias como esta no códgo porque deposi vou comprar usuario e senha, e o valor que digito nao  sempre vem vario

Comment: Se você submitar esse form os valores irão se perder, independente de onde as varáveis estejam.

Comment: Desculpa galera me expressei errado, na realidade ele tem que alterar.